# Python - how to send data from Jetson Nano to web using API

Tags: python, api

I am working on a project where I am trying to collect temperature data with the sensor, store it locally and also push them to the web where I can access it from another location/computer through API get the call.

Here is my code so far that I manage to make work for local instance where I'm saving the data into database:

```
# Import Dependencies
import sqlite3
import time
import board
from busio import I2C
import adafruit_bme680
import datetime
# Create library object using our Bus I2C port
i2c = I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme680 = adafruit_bme680.Adafruit_BME680_I2C(i2c, debug=False)

# change this to match the location's pressure (hPa) at sea level
bme680.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

# Define database name to which data will be stored
dbname = 'Sensors.db'


# Using while loop capture the data in variables and store it in database
while True:
    
    # Create the now variable to capture the current moment
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    TEMPERATURE = round(bme680.temperature,1)
    GAS = round(bme680.gas,1)
    HUMIDITY = round(bme680.humidity,1)
    PRESSURE = round(bme680.pressure,1)
    ALTITUDE = round(bme680.altitude,1)
    TIME_STAMP =(now)

    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO BME_DATA (TIME_STAMP, TEMPERATURE, GAS, HUMIDITY, PRESSURE, ALTITUDE) 
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",(TIME_STAMP, TEMPERATURE, GAS, HUMIDITY, PRESSURE, ALTITUDE))
    conn.commit()
    # Test by printing data from table BME_DATA
    #for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM BME_DATA"):   
        #print (row)
    conn.close()
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

So this works without problem, I get the readings, store them into the Sqlite3 database, however, besides storing it how do I create an API call that will send the reading every second to be available for the API call from another computer?

Comment: you need create an API service that collect your data and send it back when requested, if you right this API service in python you can use flask library

Comment: @Carlo1585 -  thank you Carlo. The API needs to keep sending the data to Azure Event Hub that is constantly listen for incoming data. So how would I do that with Flask?

Comment: sorry I miss understood u need call an API not create an API service, u can call them directly in your python code, see example and documentation https://pypi.org/project/requests/ https://realpython.com/python-requests/ https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/